# How to get translation offset while transitioning

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, slide

I have a container that is quite similar to an image slider, and designed for horizontal touch/mouse drag to move between slides. For aesthetics, an easing function is applied so that it glides into place centered on each slide when released. The method of movement is "transform: translateX()".

The problem I'm currently having is that, if the user releases, then touches and and moves it again while it's already in motion, it will jump to the slide at the end of it's transition. So for example: if you are in slide 1, move it and release while it's in the zone for slide 2, and then try to move again while it' still in motion, it will jump to slide 2 immediately, and then move from there to wherever I move my finger.

What I'm essentially looking for is a way to get the intermediate transition distance while the translation animation is running. Is there any way to measure where an element actually is in the middle of transition? If not, what are some solutions for this situation?

EDIT:
I found out the root cause to my issue, although it doesn't change the focus of the question. To give a broader explanation of what was going on, I'll include it here.

The default transition duration time was set to 300ms. When a user drags on the content by mouse or by touch, this was set to 0ms so that it wouldn't lag behind the user's movements. When released, it would be set back to 300ms. If it was grabbed again while it was in motion, it would take the position it was transitioning to and snap there when the duration was set to 0ms. This was better than then alternative of allowing it to continue to flow there while dragging again, as the content would slide under the drag point.

Comment: If we could see your javascript and css, it will help a ton. But what you will want to do is add a timer to the end of the mouse movement to prevent it from running your slide event more than once at a time.

Comment: You might consider adding some kind of timer in javascript, so that the swipe event can't be triggered again before the animation completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments on the question post, I assume this means the answer to my first question is: no, you cannot get the intermediate values directly during translation.

As to the second question, the comments mention the option of preventing activity until the animation completes. While this would work, I felt it would also diminish the UX, and so I decided to try something a little different. My solution seems to work quite well as a workaround, and so I decided to answer my own question and post it here for others. I also edited the question with a little more detail.

What I ended up doing was using a timer to *predict* the position of the intermediate value, so that if interrupted, it would appear to seamlessly stop mid-transition in the correct place.

Doing this required a little math, and the precise formula is dependent on what sort of easing is employed. "Linear" easing is the easiest to predict, but the others are quite doable with a little bit of trigonometry. I used "ease-out", so I'll include my solution for that one in pseudo-code below:

`startX + (finishX - startX) * sin((now - startTime) / transitionDuration * PI / 2)`

- `startX` is the position the slider was at when released (beginning of transition).
- `finishX` is the position the slider is moving towards (end of transition).
- `now` is the current time in milliseconds.
- `startTime` is the time the slider was at when released (beginning of transition).
- `transitionDuration` is the amount of time the transition takes to complete in milliseconds.

In summary, the above allows you to predict the position of an element during transition. While specifically written for "ease-out", it should be trivial to adapt it to other basic curves.